# Indoor Cat Palm looks very sad/dying. Please help!

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations, palm

Got this Cat Palm about 3 weeks ago and in the last week it has started to look very unhappy with yellowing of the fronds to now looking a bit brown-black just dying off. It is in our workspace so there is AC blowing all day and it has been getting direct light for about 6-8 hours but we moved it away from direct sunlight. At first we thought it needed to be watered more but now I'm thinking that it could be the sodium/fluoride in the water or a lack of proper draining. Help and advice would be greatly appreciated!! [image: the Cat Palm 3 weeks after purchase]

Answer (score 2):

It's not dying, it's just some of the fronds have suffered a bit and they look bad, but there's obvious new growth in the centre of the plant, and that's what counts. Cut the badly damaged, discoloured fronds off as close to the point of origin as you can - unfortunately, it may be exposure to the constant AC that's causing the problem, but I had a palm like this for 20 years - some of the fronds on it would periodically turn like yours have, and I just used to cut those off.

These plants prefer to be a little on the cool side and don't appreciate really dry air - that can cause leaf browning. Try to find a position for it where it gets good daylight but is not exposed to the full force of the AC all day. Don't overwater either- water when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch, but not so dry it's shrunken from the sides of the pot - water well, and if there's any left in the outer pot after 30 minutes, empty that out.